# Identity on singular strong limit cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\lambda$ be a singular strong limit cardinal.

Prove that $2^\lambda = \lambda^{\mbox{cf}\lambda}$.

It has been a while since I had to prove anything relating to cardinals, and I am not sure where to start. A little push in the right direction would be very appreciated.

(Not homework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle \lambda_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda}$ be a cofinal sequence of $\lambda$. Since $\sum_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda}\lambda_\xi =\lambda$, we get
$$
2^\lambda= 2^{\sum\lambda_\xi}=\prod_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda}2^{\lambda_\xi} \le 
\prod_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda} \lambda = \lambda^{\operatorname{cf}\lambda}
$$
since $2^{\lambda_\xi}<\lambda$ for all $\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda$. (Check that $\lambda$ is a strong limit.) In other direction, by König's lemma we get
$$
\lambda^{\operatorname{cf}\lambda}=\left( \sum_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda} \lambda_\xi\right)^{\operatorname{cf}\lambda} \le \left( \prod_{\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda} 2^\lambda\right)^{\operatorname{cf}\lambda} =2^{\lambda\cdot\operatorname{cf}\lambda}.
$$
It is easy to check that $\lambda_\xi<2^\lambda$ for all $\xi<\operatorname{cf}\lambda$ and $2^{\lambda\cdot\operatorname{cf}\lambda}=2^\lambda$.

Comment: For the second direction, you don't need König's lemma -- from $\lambda<2^\lambda$ and monotonicity of exponentiation we have $\lambda^{\text{cf}\lambda}\le(2^\lambda)^{\text{cf}\lambda}=2^{\lambda\cdot\text{cf}\lambda}=2^\lambda.$

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 Thank you for the comment.